# PLSQL record created with %rowtype being used as element for table gives compile/run error

Tags: plsql

I am declaring a table custom data-type of a record , the record is created by %rowtype of a table nemed : TMP_UNREGISTER_TAB , this table exists in the DB . While trying to execute the below plsql anon block i get the error specified below.

PLSQL CODE:

```
declare
  rec_tmp_tab TMP_UNREGISTER_TAB%rowtype ;
  v_rec_tmp_tab rec_tmp_tab;
  TYPE tab_rec_tmp IS TABLE OF v_rec_tmp_tab%type
  INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;   
  v_tab_rec_tmp tab_rec_tmp;
begin
  null;
  end;
 /
```

SCRIPT OUTPUT:

```
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 3, column 18:
PLS-00488: 'REC_TMP_TAB' must be a type
ORA-06550: line 3, column 18:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 4, column 33:
PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed
ORA-06550: line 4, column 4:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s" 
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: rec_tmp_tab is a variable, not a type.

Comment: Expanding slightly on the previous comment I think you'll need to specify `TMP_UNREGISTER_TAB%ROWTYPE` when defining `TYPE tab_rec_tmp`. Share and enjoy.

Comment: works after making table declaration as :  TYPE tab_rec_tmp IS TABLE OF rec_tmp_tab%type
   INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
  rec_tmp_tab TMP_UNREGISTER_TAB%rowtype ;
  TYPE tab_rec_tmp IS TABLE OF TMP_UNREGISTER_TAB%rowtype 
  INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;   
  v_tab_rec_tmp tab_rec_tmp;
begin
  null;
end;
/
```

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with OP's code and why this solves the problem *by editing your answer*.